# Adding data instead of replace it using nodeJs and firestore database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code:

```
function saveID(sender_psid,count){
   let data = new Object();
   data.ID = sender_psid[count];
   db.collection('users').doc('ID').set(data);
}
```

I am trying to add data to my firestore database. My current code does that but each time the function is called the new data replaces the old one instead of adding itself to the database. How do I fix that?

Comment: Did you read the docs? It looks like `set` will write or replace data. Looks like you need to use `push`. `push` will create an id for you.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: `push` is for the realtime database, not for Firestore (which OP is using because they reference `collection`). but same principal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the existing data, use `update(data)` instead of `set`

If you want to put a new document there, you can use `collection('users').add(data)` and it will use an auto generated id for the new document.

You can also add a new document to the collection by specifying a different document id to set: `collection('users').doc(id).set(data)`. In this case, id has to be a variable. Basically if you use set on a document without the merge option, you are setting the data for the specified document id. So if you use the same document id, it will overwrite the document (unless you specify the merge parameter). If you use a different id, it will add a new document using your specified id.